# JavaScript: Compare two arrays and return index of matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code.

```
function findMatch(array_1_small, array2_large) {
var ary = new Array();
for(i = 0;i < array2_large.length; i++)
{
  for(z = 0; z < array_1_small.length; z++)
  {
    if(array2_large[i] == array_1_small[z])
    {
     var idx = array2_large.indexOf(array2_large[i]);
      ary.push(idx);
    }
  }

}
return ary;
}
```

That takes the following arrays.

```
var all_SMS_TO = ["0861932936", "0871355066", "0874132026", "0872908445", "0874132026"];
var all_FORM_NUMBERS = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "0871355066",""];
```

The sole purpose is to find a match and return the index of the match on the 'all_form_numbers array.

On calling the code

```
var a = findMatch(all_SMS_TO, all_FORM_NUMBERS);
console.log("Match Found " + a);
```

I get the following output.

```
Match Found: 6
```

Which is correct, however when I alter the all_form_Numbers array to

```
var all_FORM_NUMBERS = ["", "0871355066", "", "", "", "", "0871355066",""];
```

I get The following output.

```
Match Found: 1,1
```

Could somebody help me with this so it should output;

```
Match Found 1, 6.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `i` is the index? `ary.push(i)`. IndexOf will do another O(n) search, and return the first index it finds, which you don't need in your case since you know the index already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Variables `i` and `z` should be declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: `var a = all_FORM_NUMBERS.map((n, i) => all_SMS_TO.includes(n) ? i : -1).filter(n => n != -1)` https://jsfiddle.net/d5waz2bL/

Comment: Very clever ideas here especially with the map! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
function findMatch(array_1_small, array2_large) {
var ary = new Array();
for(i = 0;i < array2_large.length; i++)
{
  for(z = 0; z < array_1_small.length; z++)
  {
    if(array2_large[i] == array_1_small[z])
    {
      ary.push(i);
    }
  }

}
return ary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
var idx = array2_large.indexOf(array2_large[i]);
```

you are searching for the index of the value 0871355066 in the array array2_large  twice and as per the definition of indexOf it will  returns the position of the **first** occurrence of a specified value.

This is why you are getting index **value 1 twice since its the index of first occurrence**.

For solution Just push the variable i value into the array ary. Which is already the index value of array2_large in the loop.

```js
function findMatch(array_1_small, array2_large) {
var ary = new Array();
for(i = 0;i < array2_large.length; i++)
{
  for(z = 0; z < array_1_small.length; z++)
  {
    if(array2_large[i] == array_1_small[z])
    {
      ary.push(i);
    }
  }

}
return ary;
}


var all_SMS_TO = ["0861932936", "0871355066", "0874132026", "0872908445", "0874132026"];
//var all_FORM_NUMBERS = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "0871355066",""];

var all_FORM_NUMBERS = ["", "0871355066", "", "", "", "", "0871355066",""];


var a = findMatch(all_SMS_TO, all_FORM_NUMBERS);
console.log("Match Found " + a);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It worked and saved me a headache! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push the index `i` here is the fixed code (you can also declare an array as `var res = [];`

```
function findMatch(arraySmall, arrayLarge) {
  var res = []
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLarge.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arraySmall.length; j++) {
      if (arrayLarge[i] === arraySmall[j]) {
        res.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this on O(n+m) runtime complexity by creating a lookup table of positions first. Then you map each element from the first array to all positions and collect these indices in a Set to only leave unique values.

Try this:

```js
var all_SMS_TO = ["0861932936", "0871355066", "0874132026", "0872908445", "0874132026"];
var all_FORM_NUMBERS = ["", "0871355066", "", "", "", "", "0871355066",""];

function findMatch(array_1_small, array2_large) {
    var positions = Array.from(array2_large.entries()).reduce((acc, t) => {
        var index = t[0]
        var element = t[1]
        if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            acc[element] = []
        }
        acc[element].push(index)
        return acc
    }, {})
    var result = new Set()
    array_1_small.forEach(x => {
        if (positions[x] === undefined) {
            return
        }
        positions[x].forEach(index => result.add(index))
    })
    return Array.from(result)
}

console.log("Match found: " + findMatch(all_SMS_TO, all_FORM_NUMBERS))
```